# All website text is bold on safari on Mac

Tags: css, macos, safari

In Safari the whole text of my site is rendered as bold, can anyone help me and understand why?

You can find my site here [Site Link](http://dare-architettura.net/sito/index.php/en/) and my [LESS CSS Stylesheet here](http://dare-architettura.net/sito/templates/frontend/less/template.less)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked Safari's font smoothing option in the settings?

Comment: @j08691 - I thought the same but it actually just turned out to be `text-shadow` causing the issue.

Comment: I tried this hack because I read on another website that this may solve the problem of all text to be bold, but even if I remove it the text remains bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the font 'Arial-BoldMT' in your font stack. Take that out!